# Removing environment specific properties from wars, ears, and jars

Tags: deployment, weblogic

At my company, we use Weblogic (depending upon the installation anywhere between versions 6.1 to 11g).

Right now, we embed environment specific variables into our ears, jars, and wars. This even includes the `weblogic.xml` file where we have something like this:

```
<working-dir>/opt/bea/wl61/server/domains/deploy/prod3/temp/work</working-dir>
```

That means we have to rebuild the same jars, ears, and wars for each and every environment. And, if there's a change in the environment, we have to rebuild and redeploy the wars, ears, and jars. You can imagine the issues and problems we have with build and release management (which is my job).

At my last position, we used JBoss, and somehow were able to create generic and deployable ears. I would have Hudson build an ear that the developers could use for their testing. This same ear could then be passed to our QA team in their environment, to UAT, staging, and into production.

We could do this amazing feat because we configured JBoss to look for properties files OUTSIDE or the ear itself. There was a `config` directory that was a sibling to the `deploy` directory that contained any needed properties files. Is it possible to setup Weblogic to do the same thing?

We need a way to do this with minimal code changes. I've already examined the source, and we don't specify the directory name when we specify loading the values in the properties files. Therefore, we might be able to do this with some sort of `CLASSPATH` idea.

I understand that these properties must live somewhere, but I would prefer if it could be configured in the environment, and maybe done by having the path relative to the `deploy` directory. I want to use the same ear, jar, and war files no matter what system you are on: Windows PC desktop, Linux, Mac, or Solaris server.

The toughest issue will be our `weblogic.xml` embedded path. Can that path be relative to the deploy directory and not from the root of the system?

As I stated before, I'm the build manager, so as far as everyone is concerned, this is **my** headache, and not their problem. If deployments don't go well, the *Finger 'o Blame* can point directly at me.

In order to get this to done I have to be able to find a solution that's simple for us to implement. We can't rewrite everything and change everything around. Otherwise, I can't get the other teams to do this. After all, it's my issue and not theirs. We need something with minimal coding changes (preferably none) and minimal changes in our Weblogic setup. I want something that in Version 3.4 of our software, we do it the old fashion environment specific way, but in Version 3.5, we can deploy in an environmentally neutral way and do that with minimal changes in our deployment environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can feel your pain - I went through the same process at a couple of companies. You have a couple of options that would be a significant improvement from your current setup:

1) Modify the `CLASSPATH` to use an external directory / properties file that overrides everything that is in the ear file. This is easy to implement but can get out of hand without the proper standards/governance.

2) Use deployment plans to define environment specific variables. However, deployment plans were not introduced until the WebLogic 9.2.

3) Roll all of your environment specific files in to its own jar. All environments would be pointing to the same file but it would be building out different contents based on your build process. Advantages - Single file that contains all the props, easy to move, etc. Disadvantages - Cannot change properties on the fly and force a reload from the JVM.

There may be other options based on the repository. IMHO, all of these work more or less the same - It's the process and enforcing it that prevents issues.

Comment: Thanks. I figured we could do #1. That's what we did with JBoss, but the people here didn't think this would work with Weblogic. I also knew about #2, but we mainly did #1. However, we did get the developers to use the same *.properties file, so we didn't have a dozen or so to manage. #2 might be good for server information, but we still have many sites on 6.1 #3 is a very interesting idea. Normally I say the deployment people in IT have to manage the properties, but here, it's CM, so this will at least keep us in the loop when there are property changes. Of course, it's more stuff to track